# How to get user hour of the week in Ruby

Tags: ruby, date, time, hour

I want to get the current hour of the week in which day starts from Sunday.

Consider current time is

```
Time.now
 => 2014-10-29 12:09:23PM +0530
```

The result should be : 84

Explanation:

```
Sunday - 24 hours
Monday - 24 hours
Tuesday - 24hours
Wednesday - 12 hours

Total: 84
```

How can get the user hour of the week. Is there any method available in Ruby ? Or how to do it without Ruby method.

Comment: What have you tried to do?  That will let us help you figure out where you have gone wrong.

Comment: @vgoff How to get user hour of the week. see updated question.

Comment: Have you tried getting the day of the week and multiplying the completed days by 24 and adding on the rest? I wouldn't expect anything to give you this in a single function call - you'll need to do the maths. You should also be aware that days don't always have 24 hours, due to DST - do you need to take account of that?

Comment: Your edit only provides more rhetoric about your wanted solution, which was obvious, I think, initially in your question.  What have you tried to do that is failing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the day of the week and hour of the day using [`Time#wday`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Time.html#method-i-wday) and [`Time#hour`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Time.html#method-i-hour).

```
Time.now.wday
#=> 3
Time.now.hour
#=> 14
```

The rest is basic mathematics.

Answer (score 2):

Even though I upvoted Yu Hao, I must say it's not a good approach if you want to pay attention to the concerns Jon Skeet raised. To that end, here's another approach:

```
(Time.now - (Date.today - Date.today.wday).to_time) / 3600
```

`Date.today` is, well, today. If you subtract the number of days since the week started, you get Sunday. Convert it to `Time` and it's the midnight when Sunday began. Subtraction gives you number of seconds between then and now. Divide by `3600` (and optionally round) to get number of hours. The DST details should be transparently handled by `Time#-`.

**EDIT:** Timezones... Run this before:

```
ENV['TZ']='EST5EDT'
```

(be sure to reset it back to what it used to be afterwards, in case anyone else needs to know time and didn't count on you switching timezones.) You can also use `"America/New_York"` instead. See [tz list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) for details.

Comment: How do i get the above calculation done in EDT timezone in ruby.